# How can i add price input field for all currency (different price for all currency ) in product form magento 2

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento2

[image]

How can i add price input field for all currency (different price for all currency ) in product form magento 2

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually add price for each and every currency. You can add the price which is for base currency for EG (USA). Now you can allow which currency you want for your magento store.

Go to `Stores > Configure > General > Currency Setup` section from the main admin panel. Here, you will be able to change the Base and Default currencies for your Store from the list.

Now form `Stores > Currency Rates` you can choose your import service and import currency exchange rates of currency.

In Frontend You will see the currency switcher visible when there are more then one currency allowed in your store.

Thats it you can now enjoy Magento Magic.

Comment: hello there, Thank you so much to give an answer to my question, actually i need to save different different price for different different Currencies i need input boxes for all Currencies, so i can save price for a product (like: rs. 100, $120 US and $40CAD ), Actually i am anable to find the controller and product form where the price filed is generated, Please tell me if you are unable to understand the problem i mentioned.

Comment: This is managed by magento you want to add manually for each product ?

Comment: Yes, I want to add manually for each product and for each Currency:)

Comment: I don't think its feasible nor its a good Idea As you may need to modify the pricing a lot in frontend also. You can add different rates in currency rates manually from currency rates I have shown above but It will be applied to every products.

Comment: First of all thanks for your response, Actually, I want to save different different price for  different different Currencies (it will be different for all products) and for front-end when user select or change the Currency, price will change according to saved price as per Currency.